# How can I block an IP, if I'm getting many http requests in a second?

Tags: webserver, http, denial-of-service, apache

If some one tried force burst attack on my website, how can I block them?

Ideally, I want to block an IP if I have many http/Apache requests in a second.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

fail2ban can be configured to do this. You can configure it to trigger on a regex match in a logfile and if it happens too many times per minute (not sure if it goes to second resolution but just multiply whatever you were thinking per second by 60) and it can drop the client IP into the iptables packet filter or whatever other action you want taken. Or you can use the iptables recent module and adapt what I've done here for SIP brute force attacks to use with your web server:

> ```
> # Deal with SIP brute forcing
> iptables -N SIP_WHITELIST
> # home
> iptables -A SIP_WHITELIST -s 1.2.3.0/24 -m recent --remove --name SIP -j ACCEPT
> # voip provider
> iptables -A SIP_WHITELIST -s 4.5.6.0/24 -m recent --remove --name SIP -j ACCEPT
> # remote location
> iptables -A SIP_WHITELIST -s 7.8.9.0/24 -m recent --remove --name SIP -j ACCEPT
>
> iptables -N SIP_BRUTEFORCE
> iptables -A SIP_BRUTEFORCE -m recent --set --name SIP
> iptables -A SIP_BRUTEFORCE -p udp --dport 5060 -m state --state NEW -j SIP_WHITELIST
> iptables -A SIP_BRUTEFORCE -m recent --update --seconds 30 --hitcount 3 --name SIP -j LOG
> iptables -A SIP_BRUTEFORCE -m recent --update --seconds 30 --hitcount 3 --name SIP -j DROP
>
> iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 5060 -m state --state NEW -j SIP_BRUTEFORCE
> ```

**Source:** https://web.archive.org/web/20180901235739/http://tracyreed.org/blog/2010/12/26/sip-brute-force-attacks

Answer (score 18):

[fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) is an easy-to-implement solution in these cases.

Add a `block-all-dem-noobs.conf` file to your `filter.d` directory, something like this

```
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*"GET.*
```

*Translation: a RegExp to find GET requests*

Then create a new entry in your `jail.conf`, something like this

```
[block-all-dem-noobs]
enabled = true
port = http,https
filter = block-all-dem-noobs
logpath = /var/log/httpd/access.log
maxretry = 100
findtime = 5
bantime = 600
action = iptables[name=HTTP, port=http, protocol=tcp]
```

*Translation: Look through my `access.log` file, then block for 600 seconds (10 minutes) the IP addresses that made 100 requests in 5 seconds*

One major drawback, though, is that this might produce false positives for [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)ed users, as they'll all appear as one IP address to you.

Comment: After apply your config:

Starting fail2ban: ERROR  NOK: ("No 'host' group in '^ -.*GET'",)

I change the failregex to:

failregex = ^(?P<host>1.2.3.4) -.*GET

See http://serverfault.com/questions/516675/how-to-add-a-jail-for-specific-ips-in-fail2ban

Comment: Is this answer up to date?

Comment: @BrunoPhilipe I believe it is. In my opinion, fail2ban has proven itself to be a timeless solution, like SSH or HTTP themselves. It's fast, introduces minimal overhead, and gets the job done with simple rules. It's probably worth it to check. I've also just fixed the filter since it wasn't extracting the host originally. It should now be working.

Comment: @Adi Indeed it worked, but like @shakaran said, you need a HOST capture group. I fixed mine with `failregex = ^(?P<host>[^\s]+) -.*GET`. Thanks!

Comment: After `fail2ban start` got `fail2ban.actions.action: ERROR  iptables -N fail2ban-HTTP#012iptables -A fail2ban-HTTP -j RETURN#012iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport http -j fail2ban-HTTP returned 200`
After replacing `iptables` by `iptables-multiport` it worked (see [https://serverfault.com/a/919822/388334]).

Comment: I don't think fail2ban is the right tool for the job here. See https://serverfault.com/a/761679/301208 for details. Try mod_evasive and/or mod_qos instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can configure Apache mod_evasive module. This module provides a very basic function by keeping a hash table of IPs and pages requested and when a threshold level is exceeded on a  target page or site it will “block” the IP with a 403 “Forbidden” error. For configuration details you read "[How to Stop an Apache DDoS Attack with mod_evasive](http://systembash.com/content/how-to-stop-an-apache-ddos-attack-with-mod_evasive/)".