# Block access from an IP that tries too many requests to Apache server XAMPP / Windows

Tags: windows, apache, windows-server, xampp

I have a VPS server with Windows 2016 Server and use XAMPP as Apache Server. Yesterday I receied too many requests from 1-2 IPs. How can I detect how many requests I get per 10 seconds and block them?

Comment: Try this https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35773/how-can-i-block-an-ip-if-im-getting-many-http-requests-in-a-second

Comment: i am running on windows , fail2ban is working with wind?

Comment: My machine runs on windows , can i run fail2ban on windows server?

Comment: @GiorgiShonia no, but it gets you on the path. You are looking for something like fail2ban for Windows. There are many options, and we do not recommend particular products on this site.

Comment: @schroeder yes now i have point , thank for answers.